# Logitech G902 Chaos Spectrum mouse macro butons siezing up computer in Minecraft

Tags: mouse, minecraft, logitech

I have an issue where if I press a macro assigned to a mouse button it siezes up my entire computer for a bit less than a second while running minecraft.  I have assigned the macros while in windows using the logitech gaming software which is not available on linux.  Not getting any lag anywhere else while using the macros.